# 'li' + float crashes Internet Explorer 6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, joomla1.5

I know. The dreaded ugly browser we don't want to support, but, it seems it couldn't be simpler to crash this thing.

[The URL](http://www.patel-products.com/patel_products/)

The images gallery is a Joomla Plugin (Sigplus), and it works fine with all other standard browsers. In Internet Explorer, it was not showing correctly. All the images were showing in one line vertically, one below the other. But the browser would not hang or crash and the gallery worked as well.

The following is a Joomla plugin, and I didn't want to mess with how it works, so, for Internet Explorer I added a simple rule in the header:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <style>
        li
        {
            float:left;
            margin-right:5px;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

This fixed the issue, and the gallery shows up as it should. But, as you scroll down, and as you reach the last row of images, Internet Explorer hangs and crashes.

I tried deleting the last five images thinking it was something to do with the images themselves. But now it hangs on the current last row and crashes.

What could it be?

Comment: IE6 has been put to rest - http://ie6funeral.com/ - large companies such as Google and Amazon no longer support it as well. http://lifehacker.com/5460043/google-apps-drops-support-for-ie6 http://forabeautifulweb.com/blog/about/internet_explorer_6_no_longer_supported_by_amazon/

Comment: Forget IE6. The funeral already happened. Just for fun, count how many hours you've wasted making your stuff IE6 compatible over the years.

Comment: The poor guy probably just has shitty boss :(

Comment: Some of us work for companies that support user-bases that are -stuck- with IE6. Large corporations have large momentum and costs associated with upgrading from legacy software. They need to security test, integrate with their intranet macros, or whatever else. Get over the fact that it's tricky to code for. He has a question, he needs help. Are you telling him not to support his customers?

Comment: +1 for awesome.  I feel like every time a developer crashes IE6 purposefully and willingly, some measure of good karma is restored to the universe.

Comment: @DMin: Does it crash with JavaScript disabled?

Comment: Disabled JavaScript, still crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some solutions that might (or might not work):

1. Add a clearing div at the end of your LIs
2. Switch from the XHTML Transitional doctype to the HTML5 or XHTML Strict doctype
3. Position the UL container relative
4. Set `zoom:1` on the UL and/or the LIs
5. Set `height:1%` on the UL and/or the LIs

There are some of the standard things that I do when IE just sucks at life.

Comment: 1 is not IE specific. 2 would only force IE to use w3 box model. 3, 4 and 5 are common [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) fixes. One of them *may* fix the problem. I would opt for a combination of 3 and 4.

Comment: Follwed all the steps(except 1) - After it worked tried all combinations and found the right answer was <ul> had to be set to zoom:1; Thanks brother! :)